# How can I make a cumulative filter with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This is my method, I am filtering by only one, I need them to be cumulative

```
private IQueryable<PublicationModel> FilterByTreatmentStatus(IQueryable<PublicationModel> selectedData, int? filterTreatmentOption)
        {
            if (filterTreatmentOption.HasValue)
            {
                switch (filterTreatmentOption)
                {
                    case (int)PublicationTreatStatus.NotTreated:
                        return selectedData.Where(x => x.PublicationStatus == 0);
                    case (int)PublicationTreatStatus.Treated:
                        return selectedData.Where(x => x.PublicationStatus == 1);
                    case (int)PublicationTreatStatus.TreatedWithoutProvidence:
                        return selectedData.Where(x => x.PublicationStatus == 2);
                    default:
                        return selectedData;
                }
            }

            return selectedData;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go - work with flags, so your enum can hold multiple values

```
[Flags]
public enum FilterTreatmentOption
{
    NotTreated = 1,
    Treated = 2,
    TreatedWithoutProvidence = 4
}


private IQueryable<PublicationModel> FilterByTreatmentStatus(IQueryable<PublicationModel> selectedData, FilterTreatmentOption filterTreatmentOption)
{
    if (filterTreatmentOption.HasFlag(PublicationTreatStatus.NotTreated))
        selectedData = selectedData.Where(x => x.PublicationStatus == 0);
    if (filterTreatmentOption.HasFlag(PublicationTreatStatus.Treated))
        selectedData = selectedData.Where(x => x.PublicationStatus == 1);
    if (filterTreatmentOption.HasFlag(PublicationTreatStatus.TreatedWithoutProvidence))
        selectedData = selectedData.Where(x => x.PublicationStatus == 2);
    return selectedData;
}
```